# External screen top resolution lost during sleep mode

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, resolution, xorg

I am under Ubuntu 20.04, on a laptop with an external screen with resolution 1920x1080 plugged in HDMI, and the laptop screen disabled.

On occasions, when my computer screen is in sleep mode, but without any clear reason, my screen remains locked in sleep mode. The computer is working fine but the link with the screen is somehow severed.

So I have to switch back to the laptop screen. I then discover that Ubuntu (inside arandr or xrandr, so Xorg, I guess) does see the external screen but does not propose anymore the top resolution of the screen (1920x1080). Instead it proposes lower resolutions (which work fine) and also 1920x1080i which does not work well (the screen flickers in this mode).

After some time (one or two hours) or somehow random manipulations (e.g., putting the laptop in sleep mode for a few minutes), the adequate resolution might be available again. Sometimes, I have to restart the computer.

Would have suggestions to recover the screen at proper resolution when something like that happens? (Of course, I tried various obvious actions like unplugging and replugging the screen!)